# Does the Serving URL of an Image in Google Cloud Storage Ever Change?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I use Google Image API get_serving_url to serve images stored in GCS. The get_serving_url is much more expensive in terms of time, comparing to datastore access.

Does the URL ever change? Is it a good idea to get serving url once and store in datastore for further reference?

Here's the time profiling of the request,

```
Total 999 ms
memcache to get BlobStore key: 1-3 ms
image.GetUrlBase: 903 ms
```

Part of the code to get serving urls,

```
class Post(ndb.model):
  files = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(repeated=True)

  def serving_urls(self):
    futures = [get_serving_url_async(blob_key=f, secure_url=True) for f in   self.files]
    ndb.Future.wait_all(futures)
    return [f.get_result() for f in futures]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that you only have to call it once, right? Not every time you serve an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not change, unless you call one of the delete methods (`delete_serving_url` or `delete_serving_url_async`).